# convert a arraylist to string

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I convert a arraylist to a string?

Comment: Quite literally: `myArrayList.ToString();`

Comment: What is *in* the arraylist, and what do you want the string to be? i.e. example input and output please...

Comment: Please give an example, so that others can easily understand what you want to do.

Comment: If you understood boxing/unboxing at all and why generics saved our a$$es in .NET 2.0, you would *not* use an ArrayList. Use a `List<string>` to get compile-time type safety.

Answer (score 13):

An [ArrayList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.aspx) could contain any object instance. So converting it to a string doesn't make much sense. It would be much more meaningful if you were using a generic `List<string>` because in this case you know that it is a collection of strings. Then you could join those strings by some separator. Example:

```
var list = new List<string>(new[] { "value 1", "value 2", "value 3" });
string result = string.Join("|", list.ToArray());
// at this stage result will be equal to "value 1|value 2|value 3"
```

Comment: +1 to Darin Dimitrov.

ArrayList is like a resizeable array. It is a collection and stores value as an object. New items can be added or removed without performance loose.

http://www.defaultdotaspx.com/Answer.aspx?QuestionType=ASPNET&QuestionID=222

Why do you really need to convert it to a string?

Answer (score 5):

The `ArrayList` may have anything in it that derives from Object, so I would suggest the following:

```
ArrayList sl = new ArrayList() {1, 23.33m, "hello", DateTime.Now};
var result = string.Join(",", sl.ToArray()
    .Select(o => o.ToString()).ToArray());
```

this will give you a string that represents all values separated by a comma

Hope that is what you were after

Answer (score 2):

It isn't at all what you mean (plus, `ArrayList` is in very low use now - look at generics instead, i.e. `List<T>`) - but if you just want the concatenated output of each object:

```
    ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList() { 1, "abc", 345.67M };
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (object obj in arrayList) sb.Append(obj);
    string s = sb.ToString();
```

(I've deliberately not added anything in the middle like commas, but you can see how it can be extended)

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to guess exactly what you want to happen here. If you can describe the types of  objects in the ArrayList, the method you want to use to generate a string from each of them, and what you want to do with those resulting strings, then you can get towards a meaningful answer to your question.

For example, if you wanted to take the default string representation of each item in the list and concatenate into a CSV, you could so something like:-

```
var text = string.Join(",", myArray.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray());
```